# is it possible to change style of some words in a paragaph with the help of css without using any html tag on those words

Tags: html, css

Is it possible? I want to change the style of some words in a paragraph with the help of css without using any html tag on those specific word. like , etc. 
Waiting for positive reply. Thanks:

Comment: Sorry to be negative, but you're not going to get a positive reply.

Comment: malik saab kisi ka answer accept kar b lain.

Answer (score 6):

CSS can select only elements and pseudo-elements. You cannot select words.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with only CSS. But you *could* use JavaScript to match specific words and dynamically wrap the words in an HTML element (e.g. a `span`), and style that with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible with pure css but there some pseudo-elements which have limited scope like

`:first-letter`, `:first-line`

Answer (score 1):

without Tags it is not possible. even Jquery can not understand that what you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Not possibble with only CSS, but with for example jQuery you can search some words into a text and change the style for example:

```
$('p').html(html.replace(/world/gi, '<strong>$&</strong>'));
```