# change html page style

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find text string in jQuery and make it bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794851/find-text-string-in-jquery-and-make-it-bold)

I have some text on my html page (with accents on leters) :

```
<p>
some téxt, some text, some téxt, some text, some text, some téxt, 
</p>
```

My goal is to set bold style for all occurences of "**text**" and "**téxt**"

Is it possible ?

thank you

Valeriane

Comment: Same issue : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794851/find-text-string-in-jquery-and-make-it-bold

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027828/is-it-possible-to-change-style-of-some-words-in-a-paragaph-with-the-help-of-css

Comment: I think [this](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule) could help you.

Comment: What part are you struggling with, the matching of the accents or the bolding?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the following in your case,

```
str.replace(/(t.xt)/g, "<b>"+text+"</b>);
```

so we need to use a callback function :

```
//Assuming you can retrieve the text from the p tag or from the entire page
var str = "some téxt, some text, some téxt, some text, some text, some téxt, " 

str.replace(/(t.xt)/g, function(match){
  return "<b>"+match+"</b>";
})
```

You can add this snippet to `document.onload` or  `$().function(){...}`

Comment: text and téxt are used as an example, I need something functional in any case

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700636/using-javascript-to-perform-text-matches-with-without-accented-characters

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text is in:

```
<p id="txt">
some téxt, some text, some téxt, some Text, some text, some téxt, xyz
</p>



var bold = ['some','text', 'xyz']; // words to bold
var content = document.getElementById('txt');//content to find those words
var regExp = new RegExp('('+bold.join('|')+')', "gi"); //build regular expression (i means case insensitive)

content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML.replace(regExp, "<strong>$1</strong>"); //find and bold
```

Comment: text and téxt are used as an example, I need something functional in any case