# I want to style only first lines in the below div with out using internal div and spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to style the only Q) text...... in the below div if use demo:first-line property only first line is getting style but i want to this for all Q) texts...
how to achieve this....(with only one div )

```
<div id="demo">
     Q)On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document.<br />
     A)You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building 
       blocks.When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look.<br /><br />


     Q)Most controls offer a choice of using the look from the current theme or using a format that you specify directly.<br />
     A)To change the overall look of your document, choose new Theme elements on the Page Layout tab. To change the 
       looks available in the Quick Style gallery, use the Change Current Quick Style Set command.<br /><br />

     Q)You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks.<br />
     A)When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look. You can easily 
       change the formatting of selected text in the document text by choosing a look for the selected text from the Quick
       Styles gallery on the Home tab <br />
</div>
```

Comment: You need to put you `Q)text...` in `spans` and style them

Comment: without using spans how to achieve this..

Comment: almost impossible without child elements

Comment: Thank you for your feedback

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027828/is-it-possible-to-change-style-of-some-words-in-a-paragaph-with-the-help-of-css

Comment: There was once a proposal for this kind of structure, `<dialog>`, which never made it. (Not to be confused with the other proposal for `<dialog>`, about a dialog box.) Currently, the recommended way is to use a `<dl>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<p>` elements, you can style them using the selectors (nth-of-type(odd)).

```
<div id="demo">
     <p>Q)On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document.</p><br />
     <p>A)You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks.When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look.</p><br /><br />


    <p> Q)Most controls offer a choice of using the look from the current theme or using a format that you specify directly.</p><br />
    <p>A)To change the overall look of your document, choose new Theme elements on the Page Layout tab. To change the looks available in the Quick Style gallery, use the Change Current Quick Style Set command.</p><br/><br/>

    <p> Q)You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks.</p><br/>
    <p> A)When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look. You can easily change the formatting of selected text in the document text by choosing a look for the selected text from the Quick Styles gallery on the Home tab </p><br />
</div>


#demo p:nth-of-type(odd){
    color:red;
}
```

Regards,
VISHAL V M

Comment: If you can give the content <p> tags better give them classes also. For future maintainability.